# sendgrid is messing with my django models in views file

Tags: django, sendgrid

In my views file, I add a feedback function that send email, I import this:

```
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *
from django.conf import settings
```

In the same file, I have this views:

```
def post_by_category(request, category_slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    posts = get_list_or_404(Post.objects.order_by('-id'),category=category)
    posts = pg_helpers.pg_records(request, posts, 3)
    context = {
        'category':category,
        'posts': posts,
        }

    return render(request, 'blog/post_by_category.html', context)
```

The `post_by_category` would raise an error `type object 'Category' has no attribute 'model'` when it tries to `get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)` because queryset is this kind of category: `<class 'sendgrid.helpers.mail.category.Category'>`

If I remove the import, it works normally, but I would like to be able to send email from feedback of users. What can I do? Rename the Category?

Comment: Okay, I renamed my Category into PCategory and it works. However I still would like to know if anyone has better solution? I take the code from sendgrid website and they import everything. If someone knows a more parsimonious import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not show the import of your app's Category model. However, it sounds like you have a model named `Category` that is conflicting with a model in the sendgrid module with the same name.

One way to avoid renaming yours, as you said you tried in the note, is to use:

`from appname import Category as PCategory`

Then in the view function use this instead:
`category = get_object_or_404(PCategory, slug=category_slug)`

This allows you to keep your model as originally named, but use the non-conflicting `PCategory` or any other alternative name.